# Is it possible to use Google Apps Standard user accounts with OpenID?

Tags: django, openid, google-apps

I am using Google Apps Standard for all of my email and calendaring. I am trying to implement a Single Sign On solution with a Django app that I am building, but I am running into an issue with using my Apps account to login.

I have all of the authentication code in place to authenticate with OpenID's in Django. When I hit the /admin page, it redirects me to the Google sign-on page.

When I enter my Google Apps username (name@mydomain.com) and password, it will not authenticate. When I use my Gmail username and password, then I am in no problem.

I am using https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id as the OpenId provider URL.

There are a couple of questions:

- Can I even use Google Apps Standard as an OpenID provider?
- Do I need to enable this somehow?
- Am I using the wrong server url, should this be something that is specific to my domain?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of looking around, I found a great article that walks through setting up your domain as an openid provider so that it works with your Google Apps domain.

This is really useful if you have your domain (example.com) and you use Google apps to get email at (name@example.com).

You can configure your domain to serve the proper XRDS file that will redirect OpenID authentication requests to Google Apps for authentication.

This article will walk you though all of the steps needed to get going:
http://jeremiahlee.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-to-setup-openid-with-google-apps/